# Convert a Twitter Bootstrap Uncloseable Modal into a Closeable One

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create a modal that can't be closed. This is on purpose. However, after ten seconds, I want the user to be able to close the modal either by pressing the escape key or clicking outside of it. Can this be done? Here is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">A Modal That Can't Be Closed</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>There is no way to close this modal. I would like to make it so that after ten seconds, pressing the escape key or clicking outside the modal causes the modal to close.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('The modal has been open for 10 seconds.');
                }, 10000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I created a feature request to add a method for updating modal options after creation.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35664

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, the cleanest way to do this involves invoking some methods of the **modal** object which aren't necessarily part of the public API, even though the methods are technically public in their scope.  This means that if you put this code into production you'll have to be careful to check for changes in the **bootstrap-modal.js** implementation whenever you upgrade.  Here's how to do it:

### JS

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
  // hold a ref to the modal object
  var mdl = $(this).data('modal')

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('The modal has been open for 10 seconds.');

    // enable keyboard escaping
    mdl.options.keyboard = true
    mdl.escape()

    // but re-disable it for future show events ;)
    mdl.options.keyboard = false

    // replace refocus handler with hide() invocation
    mdl.$backdrop.off('click')
    mdl.$backdrop.click($.proxy(mdl.hide, mdl))

  }, 10000); // ten seconds
});
```

### [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eh8XqJT3hlZGyQD3ya2s?p=preview)

The relevant code is in the **script.js** in the live example, and defaults to 3 seconds.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I also appreciate the caution about the code possibly breaking with future versions of Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Good answer. Additionally, for bootstrap 3 one has to use data('bs.modal') instead.

Comment: Anyone able to get the clicking outside the modal working in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @bbodenmiller: For Bootstrap 3, you need to add `mdl.options.backdrop = true;` to let it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution : http://jsfiddle.net/g5bDC/1/

Just add a disabled button (here in footer) and enabled it after X secs

HTML :

```
<div class="modal-footer"> 
    <a href="#" class="btn" disabled=disabled id="closeBtn" aria-hidden="true">Close</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled').attr('data-dismiss', 'modal');
    }, 5000);
});
```

EDIT : 
According to MartinHN here is an updated version : http://jsfiddle.net/g5bDC/2/

JS is now :

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
    $('#closeBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#closeBtn').removeAttr('disabled').attr('data-dismiss', 'modal');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: A small improvement would be to set the `disabled` attribute before calling `setTimeout` to make it work if you launch the modal again without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking specifically for the escape key and clicking outside of the modal functionality