# Bootstrap modal backdrop = 'static' not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

First, I open my modal using this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Then, in another situation, I need that this same modal does not close when pressing ESC/clicking outside, so I use this:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

But once I open my modal by the first method, the second one doesn't work. Any hints?

How can I force `backdrop` value switch to work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue.

Once the modal has been hidden bootstrap data still remains on it. To prevent that I had the following:

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show'); //display something
//...

// if you don't want to lose the reference to previous backdrop
$('#myModal').modal('hide'); 
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal',null); // this clears the BS modal data
//...

// now works as you would expect
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop:'static', keyboard:false});
```

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem with Bootstrap 4.1.1 and it only worked when I added the data attributes to the html

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  style="display: block;" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
...
```

Comment: This is the solution also for Bootstrap 3 in case you open modals using markup instead of JS methods

Comment: Yes, this is also true even if the modal was opened using Javascript.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to [Daniele Piccioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4247487/daniele-piccioni) but a bit more concise:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: false, show: true});
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

This is for `Bootstrap 3.+`

See also: [Change Bootstrap modal option once it already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806816/change-bootstrap-modal-option-once-it-already-exists)

Answer (score 7):

For Bootstrap 5+, `data-bs-backdrop="static"` html attribute should be used, this is because Bootstrap adds `bs` for their direct attributes on html tags.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to handle this:

1) You can directly add the data-attributes into the HTML -

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
style="display: block;" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```

2) You can use JQuery (For Bootstrap V4) -

```
$("#myModal").data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';
```

for Bootstrap V3 -

```
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to disable closing of a modal while an AJAX request was completing.

[@jollyGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2103802/jollygreen) got me going in the right direction, but in **bootstrap 4**, The only way I could do this pragmatically after the modal was already shown was like this:

`$("#myModal").data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';`

That is to say that between `v3` and `v4` they seem to have changed the `options` property of the `bs.modal` data object to `_config`.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular Try:

```
[config]="{backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}"
```

In the modal div. This solution is working 100%

Eg:

```
<div bsModal #dangerModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Explain you answer which will easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

*Added data-attributes in HTML*. It's working on bootstrap 4, bootstrap 3

```
<div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" *data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"*>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document"><div class="modal-content"></div></div>
</div>
```

***In jQuery***

```
$('div.modal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false
});
```