# Bootstrap Modal: Re-enable keyboard and backdrop

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I'm creating my modal with the escape key and backdrop disabled by default

```
$(modal).modal({
  backdrop: "static",
  keyboard: false
});
```

Then some time later I wanna enable them

```
$(modal).modal({
  backdrop: true,
  keyboard: true
});
```

But when I click on the backdrop or press escape nothing happens. I could recreate the entire modal but that looks broken, clumsy and hacky. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806816/change-bootstrap-modal-option-once-it-already-exists can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out boostrap 4 change structure of configuration. You should use

```
$('#basicModal').data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard = true;
$('#basicModal').data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = true;
```

See the https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvmvQB