# Block modal with "data-backdrop" and "data-keyboard" on runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I would like to block the user from exiting the modal on clicking outside or pressing ESC when an input has been changed, my attempt being:

```
$("#cadastroModal input, #cadastroModal textarea, #cadastroModal select").on('change input select select2:select', function() {
   $('#cadastroModal').attr('data-backdrop', 'static');
   $('#cadastroModal').attr('data-keyboard', false);
});
```

And while the element does change in runtime (as checked with chrome inspect element), it seems like it doesn't respect the data attributes if its already open. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to use _config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499508/5728714)

This worked:

```js
$('#cadastroModal').data('bs.modal')._config.backdrop = 'static';
$('#cadastroModal').data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard = false;
```